# Is it possible to connect python client to snowflake using oauth2?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect my python client to the snowflake warehouse using oauth2. I've seen that snowflake does support oauth2 (https://www.snowflake.com/blog/using-oauth-2-0-with-snowflake/), but couldn't find anything regarding the python client.
Is this supported?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: I am a little confused, the article you linked to says, "The access token can then be passed to one of Snowflake’s client drivers by using the OAuth authenticator. Currently, client driver support is limited to JDBC, ODBC, Python, and Go." If you are looking for a sample app -  https://github.com/sanderiam/OAuth2.0-SampleApp

Comment: thanks @RachelMcGuigan. I was looking for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, oauth is supported by snowflake-python-connector library. To use it, just use the authenticator="oauth" and specify the token when connecting to snowflake:

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    authenticator="oauth",
    user=sf_user,
    token=token,
    account=sf_account_id,
    database=database,
    schema=schema,
    warehouse=warehouse,
    role=role,
)
```